# In DC motor'name plate there is written only 12 or 24 volt there is no any description about current and power why?

Tags: motor, dc

In DC motor'name plate there is written only 12 or 24 volt there is no any description about current and power why?and in ac motore there is written all details about voltage and current and power.

Comment: Maybe the manufacturer didn't know what he had made. Anything any good would have a proper rating plate on it with the manufacturer's name and address and the model number of the device.

Comment: In any device which is run by DC there is written only voltage 12 or 24 volt.

Answer (score 1):

Consumer products are normally marked with the voltage, DC or Hz AC, and current or power. Motors made for specific products may have only what the manufacturer of the product needs for manufacturing the product. Motor sold for general use have proper rating plates with the information required by international standards.

Very small motors sold for toy and hobby use are often poorly marked. Hobby motors sold by suppliers that care about their customers identify their motors well enough so that they can be matched up with full information on their web site or in their catalog. Anything for which you can not find full information should be considered to be industrial surplus or junk.

Comment: Of course many parameters of a DC motor are easily measured. You may have to guess the others, and be a little conservative on rated power, but they can still be usable.